# Strange behavior for zsh auto completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I recently changed the domain of two of my servers from `mdorst.net` to `mars.mdorst.net`. Now when I go to ssh, one of them auto completes as expected, and the other does not.

```
$ ssh michael@o<Tab>
```

autocompletes to

```
$ ssh michael@opportunity.mars.mdorst.net
```

which is what I want. However, when I type

```
$ ssh michael@c<Tab>
```

it autocompletes to

```
$ ssh michael@curiosity.m.net
```

and places the cursor after the m.

My best guess was that it knew that I had typed both of the following

```
$ ssh michael@curiosity.mdorst.net
$ ssh michael@curiosity.mars.mdorst.net
```

before, and wanted to know which one. Extremely clever! Except that I don't want that behavior, so I went back through my `.zsh_history` and deleted all occurrences of `curiosity.mdorst.net`, and the problem persists!

This is extremely confusing to me, because I have also done `opportunity.mdorst.net` before, but this doesn't happen when I type `o<Tab>`, only when I type `c<Tab>`.

How can I make it autocomplete to the correct domain?

Comment: Have you checked `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and `/etc/hosts`? IMHO the completions are taken from those files.

Comment: @mpy I deleted my `known_hosts` file and it solved the problem (once I had ssh'd back into each host, and logged back in). Thanks. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` is gathering the information about usernames and visited hosts for `ssh` completion from the files

- /etc/hosts
- /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
- ~/.ssh/known_hosts

if the `hosts` and `known-hosts-files` style is not set. (Source: `zshcompsys` manual)

So, you should check at first place your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and delete the line with the remote computer you don't want to be completed.